# Ruby Nokogiri parsing omit duplicates

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm parsing XML files and wanting to omit duplicate values from being added to my Array.  As it stands, the XML will looks like this:

```
<vulnerable-software-list>
  <product>cpe:/a:octopus:octopus_deploy:3.0.0</product>
  <product>cpe:/a:octopus:octopus_deploy:3.0.1</product>
  <product>cpe:/a:octopus:octopus_deploy:3.0.2</product>
  <product>cpe:/a:octopus:octopus_deploy:3.0.3</product>
  <product>cpe:/a:octopus:octopus_deploy:3.0.4</product>
  <product>cpe:/a:octopus:octopus_deploy:3.0.5</product>
  <product>cpe:/a:octopus:octopus_deploy:3.0.6</product>
</vulnerable-software-list>

document.xpath("//entry[
  number(substring(translate(last-modified-datetime,'-.T:',''), 1, 12)) > #{last_imported_at} and
  cvss/base_metrics/access-vector = 'NETWORK'
  ]").each do |entry|
  product = entry.xpath('vulnerable-software-list/product').map { |product| product.content.split(':')[-2] }
  effected_versions = entry.xpath('vulnerable-software-list/product').map { |product| product.content.split(':').last }
  puts product
end
```

However, because of the XML input, that's parsing quite a bit of duplicates, so I end up with an array like `['Redhat','Redhat','Redhat','Fedora']`

I already have the `effected_versions` taken care of, since those values don't duplicate.

Is there a method of `.map` to only add unique values?

Comment: Please respect people reading from smartphones/tablets and format the code accordingly, trying to avoid horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get an array of unique values, then just call `uniq` method to get the unique values:

```
product =
  entry.xpath('vulnerable-software-list/product').map do |product|
    product.content.split(':')[-2]
  end.uniq
```

Comment: This works nicely since it's only 5 more clicks on the keyboard ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this:

```
input = ['Redhat','Redhat','Redhat','Fedora']

# approach 1
# self explanatory

result = input.uniq

# approach 2
# iterate through vals, and build a hash with the vals as keys
# since hashes cannot have duplicate keys, it provides a 'unique' check

result = input.each_with_object({}) { |val, memo| memo[val] = true }.keys

# approach 3
# Similar to the previous, we iterate through vals and add them to a Set.
# Adding a duplicate value to a set has no effect, and we can convert it to array

result = input.each_with_object.(Set.new) { |val, memo| memo.add(val) }.to_a
```

If you're not familiar with [each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), it's very similar to [reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)

Regarding performance, you can find some info if you search for it, for example [What is the fastest way to make a uniq array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276968/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-make-a-uniq-array)

From a quick test, I see these performing in increasing time. `uniq` is 5 times faster than `each_with_object`, which is 25% slower than the `Set.new` approach. Probably because sort is implemetned using C. I only tested with only an arbitrary input though, so it might not be true for all cases.